# Why is clone used here?

Tags: java, clone, vaadin-flow

I was going through a Vaadin tutorial and came across this piece of code. However I can't understand the purpose of `clone` in this scenario. Can anyone please explain?

```
/**
 * Persists or updates customer in the system. Also assigns an identifier for
 * new Customer instances.
 *
 * @param entry
 */
public synchronized void save(Customer entry) {
    if (entry == null) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,
            "Customer is null. Are you sure you have connected your form to the application as described in tutorial chapter 7?");
        return;
    }
    if (entry.getId() == null) {
        entry.setId(nextId++);
    }
    try {
        entry = (Customer) entry.clone();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    contacts.put(entry.getId(), entry);
}

/**
 * Sample data generation
 */
public void ensureTestData() {
    if (findAll().isEmpty()) {
        final String[] names = new String[] { "Gabrielle Patel", "Brian Robinson", "Eduardo Haugen",
            "Koen Johansen", "Alejandro Macdonald", "Angel Karlsson", "Yahir Gustavsson", "Haiden Svensson",
            "Emily Stewart", "Corinne Davis", "Ryann Davis", "Yurem Jackson", "Kelly Gustavsson",
            "Eileen Walker", "Katelyn Martin", "Israel Carlsson", "Quinn Hansson", "Makena Smith",
            "Danielle Watson", "Leland Harris", "Gunner Karlsen", "Jamar Olsson", "Lara Martin",
            "Ann Andersson", "Remington Andersson", "Rene Carlsson", "Elvis Olsen", "Solomon Olsen",
            "Jaydan Jackson", "Bernard Nilsen" };
        Random r = new Random(0);
        for (String name : names) {
            String[] split = name.split(" ");
            Customer c = new Customer();
            c.setFirstName(split[0]);
            c.setLastName(split[1]);
            c.setStatus(CustomerStatus.values()[r.nextInt(CustomerStatus.values().length)]);
            c.setBirthDate(LocalDate.now().minusDays(r.nextInt(365 * 100)));
            save(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `Customer` has the following data members: `private Long id, private String firstName = "", private String lastName = "", private LocalDate birthDate, private CustomerStatus status, private String email = ""`

Comment: Presumably it wants a clean reference to the object. I'm guessing to ensure that the data within the object doesn't change during or after it has been saved.

Comment: In which case is this even possible? I can't think of any such scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @shiva can be a problem when multiple threads are working with a single `Customer` instance and e.g. Thread1 tries to save it. While in the `safe` method Thread2 could then change some values of the customer and would lead to inconsistencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `save` method is public so can be called from anywhere. If someone saves a customer and later alters the customer object they have saved, you don’t want the new changes reflected in what you’ve got in `contacts`. Saving a clone there ensures that you are not affected by what they are doing.

> But assuming save method isn't called from anywhere else other than `ensureTestData()`, do we still need to clone it?

Technically on the short sight no. Whether your `ensureTestData` method saves the customer it has created or a clone of it makes no difference. In that case you would need to declare the `save` method private, though, or you won’t know when someone is introducing a call to it from somewhere. In many cases one would still clone to prevent future changes to the code from causing unwanted effects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clears things up.  But assuming `save` method isn't called from anywhere else other than `ensureTestData()`, do we still need to clone it?

Comment: @shiva the issue is not that `ensureTestData()` could be called somewhere else (it's synchronized anyway), but that the `customer` object that is passed into that function could be modified somewhere else in the meantime. To make absolutely sure that no other Thread modifies the customer instance, you have to clone it. By cloning, you make a new instance of the customer class, that has the very same values as the original one, but you can be sure that this new clone is not being referenced to anywhere else in your application.